# Python doesn't grab info due to JS

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

Below is a bit of code I am puzzled with.  I have been successful with web scraping info from other sites but this one I can't get my head around.  I believe that I am missing something due to, maybe, JS.

My end code will take the mainurl and theurl (which is a link) and add them together.  However I can even seem to be able to display theurl out.  When I go through the inspect aspect I can see what I need but in page source it is not there.  Am I missing something in my code for the JS?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

b = open('csv/homedepot.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

mainurl = "http://www.homedepot.ca" ## Main website
theurl = "https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/appliances/refrigerators-and-freezers.html" ##Target website
r = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Comment: So you're saying the actual page content is populated via Javascript…?

Comment: To me it looks that way.  Just trying to find a way to grab to info once populated into the page

Comment: For that you would need to run a headless browser which actually evaluates the Javascript and builds a DOM. Instead of doing that, analyse the page itself and the network requests it makes to get the data.